# How can I take the values from columns and send them to rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, business-intelligence

I have a dataframe with 60 columns, which most of them are just information about other sold products, it looks like this:

```
store_id|seller_id | product_0_code |product_0_value   |product_1_code |product_1_value
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 12     |    1234  |  a2356         |    52,20         |   ae822,       |    50,20
```

In order to reduce the number of columns, I've been trying to put the values from the columns in rows, something like this:

```
store_id |seller_id | product_ code |product_value 
12       |  1234    |  a2356        | 52,20
12       |  1234    |  ae822        | 50,20
```

That means, keeping the values of store_id and seller_id, but taking the values from the products_code and product_value columns and inserting them in new rows.

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), but we first need to create a MultiIndex using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
# Set index to the columns to be unaffected
new_df = df.set_index(['store_id', 'seller_id'])
# Split remaining column into a MultiIndex
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
# Stack Middle level (the numbers) into rows
new_df = new_df.stack(1).droplevel(-1)
# Join MultiIndex Columns together
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map('_'.join)
# Reset to default range index
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

*Note this assumes that the remaining columns have values separated by `_` with a number in the second split position.

`new_df`:

```
   store_id  seller_id product_code product_value
0        12       1234        a2356         52,20
1        12       1234       ae822,         50,20
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'store_id': [12], 'seller_id': [1234], 'product_0_code': ['a2356'],
    'product_0_value': ['52,20'], 'product_1_code': ['ae822,'],
    'product_1_value': ['50,20']
})
```

Answer (score 4):

`pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor` can also help in this transformation; since your columns have an order to them (some end with code, others with value):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
df.pivot_longer(index = ['store_id', 'seller_id'], 
                names_to = ['product_code', 'product_value'], 
                names_pattern = ["code$", "value$"])
 
   store_id  seller_id product_code product_value
0        12       1234        a2356         52,20
1        12       1234       ae822,         50,20
```

It is also possible to reshape using `pd.wide_to_long`.

First, reorder the columns with `str.replace`:

```py
pat = "(?P<start>.+)_(?P<middle>.+)_(?P<end>.+)"
repl = lambda m : f"{m.group('start')}_{m.group('end')}_{m.group('middle')}"
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(pat, repl, regex = True)
# or just skip the steps above and use this option from @HenryEcker
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(.+)_(.+)_(.+)', r'\1_\3_\2', regex=True)
```

Apply `pd.wide_to_long`:

```py
pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames = ['product_code', 'product_value'], 
                i = ['store_id', 'seller_id'], 
                j = 'num', 
                sep='_').droplevel('num').reset_index()

   store_id  seller_id product_code product_value
0        12       1234        a2356         52,20
1        12       1234       ae822,         50,20
```

Comment: this looks nice +10, but i'm confused. dataframes just automatically get a `pivot_longer` method once `janitor` is imported? how does that work?

Comment: pyjanitor uses [pandas-flavor](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-flavor/), that allows users to build functions/methods on pandas data frames/series.

Comment: python's pretty flexible `pd.DataFrame.my_func = some_userdefined_func` can also be used to add a function to a DataFrame. Finding wrap targets on import is a pretty similar idea if with a few more safety checks.

Comment: I think `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(.+)_(.+)_(.+)', r'\1_\3_\2', regex=True)` might be a more straightforward replace than all of those named capture groups and the lambda.

Comment: @HenryEcker, True. but my regex skills are basic (named groups sort of keep me sane).  :)